# How can I convert an FFIL suitcase file or PS1 file without an extension to otf or ttf?

Tags: fonts, font-management

I'm using a Mac (Snow Leopard) and have been given a file in FFIL format which I need to convert to ttf or otf so that I can use it to generate @font-face fonts. I also have the font as postscript type 1, again without a file extension (get info shows that it is type1). There are online generators but these do not accept the files I have as they do not have file extensions (I am definitely displaying all file extensions on my mac - finder preference).

I would prefer an open source / free solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out FontForge on SourceForge: http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/ Might do what you're looking for. For more information check out this article: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/screencast-converting-ttf2eot